# How to offer a screenshot of a Google Maps instance?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to implement a map simmilar to this: http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html

One of the desired features is ability to save **a screenshot of the visible fragment of the map**, along with the markers. Do you have some ideas how can I implement such a feature?

I know that I may use this: [http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), but it seems that Static Maps API is limited to images up to 640x640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but I think that you are forbidden from doing this by the [Google Maps terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html): the map imagery is subject to copyright. In particular, section 10 of the terms probably prohibits what you want to do (see, in particular, section 10.2). There may also be some relevant provisions in the [Google Maps Legal Notices](http://www.google.com/intl/en-us/help/legalnotices_maps.html).

Comment: thanks, ultimately we did not do this because of the legal issues, so your answer is 100% good :)