# Insert Screenshot of just captured Geocoded image?

Tags: javascript, image, geocoding

I am performing a GoogleMaps/VirtualEarth geocode-request and the resulting image ( showing the location on a map ) is displayed on my site.

The problem is, I need part of this graphic 'captured' and displayed on the form.

Is it possible to do this and add the result to the form?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389854/how-to-offer-a-screenshot-of-a-google-maps-instance

Comment: Nother Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142821/google-maps-image

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Locations), they provide such functions